# How to add a cartesian set in python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sum each Cartesian set in a list how do i do that

I am squaring every input and then creating a Cartesian set out of the nested list and appending the to a new list.

```
from itertools import product
n, k = map(int,input().split())
list1 = [[pow(int(l),2) for l in input().split()] for i in range (n)]
list2 = []
for i in product(*list1):
    list2.append(i)
```

is there a predefined function to do it?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: `list2 = [i for i in product(*list1)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to sum each tuple of the product:

```
for i in product(*list1):
    list2.append(sum(i))
```